Identify maximum in quadratic regression
I am looking for a way to find the maximum in a quadratic regression.
Specifically, I have two variables X and Y. Y is a discrete and commonly used scale representing the severity of a disease, ranging from 0 to 20 and X is a biological parameter. Since I expect the relationship between X and Y to take on an inverted u-shape, I want to find out at what level of disease severity X is greatest (e.g., let's say the maximum of X lies at Y = 13, then we can expect X to increase and then decrease before and after a disease severity of 13). I would also like to find out the predicted value of X and get a confidence interval for X.
Since I have unbalanced multi-panel data, I am looking for an approach using the nlme or lme4 packages.
Any ideas?
edit
I found the "two-line test" (Simonsohn, 2016), which fits a segmented regression based on a breakpoint (i.e. the maximum in quadratic regression) identified with a particular algorithm.
However, the procedure does not account for random variance.

"the maximum of X lies at Y = 13, then we can expect X to increase and then decrease before and after a disease severity of 13"  I think you've got X and Y the wrong way round. If not, then I don't understand your question.

A similar question Confidence interval for GLM or the maximum of a function?

If you've fitted $$\hat y = b_0 + b_1 x + b_2 x^2$$ then the gradient of that quadratic curve vanishes when $$d\hat y / dx = b_1 + 2 b_2 x = 0$$ whence at that turning point $$x = -b_1 / 2 b_2,$$ which you can calculate simply from your parameter estimates.
Naturally you should always check that
a. the model is a good idea -- by plotting the data and the fitted curve together and judging the suitability of a quadratic
b. the turning point is indeed a minimum
and
c. the turning point occurs within the data range or at least is a plausible value of $x$.
It's unclear to me why or how having unbalanced multi-panel data complicates the question, unless

Lack of balance and/or other heterogeneity makes a single model moot

You really fitted a more complicated model, in which case there isn't likely to be a simple minimum but at best the minimum is a set of points on some more complicated prediction surface. In fact, your mention of those R packages is worrying insofar as it implies that you did that.


Detail: Statistically speaking $x$ is here a variable, and not a parameter, the last term being better reserved for the quantities $\beta_0, \beta_1, \beta_2$ of which $b_0, b_1, b_2$ are estimates.

To avoid the problems with estimating the standard error of $-\hat b_1/(2\hat b_2),$ I suggest analyzing the question of testing the contrast $2(x-x^)\hat b_2 + \hat b_1$ where $x^$ is the estimated peak location and $x$ is any other location.  Intuitively, values of $x$ for which this test does not reject the null hypothesis are consistent with being a possible peak location, thereby producing fiducial limits for $x^*.$  This is sometimes known as inverse regression., q.v.

Thanks for your answer, @Nick Cox. Regarding the multi-panel nature, the dataset contains data from patients and some of them were tested over multiple years. I wanted to do something as an LMM to incorporate random effects (and possibly covariates). How could I statistically test the maximum of x?

also thanks for your comment, @whuber .

Your question about testing can't be answered well without an explicit mention of whatever model you fitted. Indeed what is X and what is Y still seems confused to me.

I am thinking of a model such as lmer(Y ~ X + I (X^2) + random(1 | patient)) , @NickCox. Y is expected to decrease linearly (disease severity will only get worse over time), while X, the biological variable, will increase as the disease worsens, but will decrease after a certain disease stage is passed.

I hope someone can follow that.  I am not a routine user of R or such models.
